# Trying to make a delete account function to a login system built in node.js using MongoDB and passport.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I followed Brad Traversy's tutorial on how to make a login site in node.js (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FOq4cUdH8k&t=4376s&ab_channel=TraversyMedia)
but I wanted to add a feature that allows the users to delete their accounts.

I tried something like this:

```
// delete handle
router.get('/delete', function(req, res) {
    req.logout(function(err) {
        const email = req.body;
        if (err) return next(err);
        User.findOneAndDelete({ email: email });
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Your account has been deleted');
        res.redirect('/users/register');
    });
});
```

But it didn't work. I can't figure out how to get the users email once he is logged in and thus can't match the user's email to the one in the database.
This is the user schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

I will upload additional code if something is unclear.
Thanks for the help.